# get ItemID for photo from STRING

Tags: android, imageview

I have name of photo stored in my database. Now i want to use that name to set the imageview of that name. i have my images in drawable folder. below is my code.

```
 ImageView mIcon = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.listImageView);
        mIcon.setImageResource(getImageId(this.context, event.getIcon()));
```

here event is my class. and `evet.getIcon()` giving me correct name what i want.

and my `getImageId()` method is here :

```
public int getImageId(Context context, String imageName) {
        return context.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/" + imageName,
                "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    }
```

and this code is in one CustomAdapter.java which extends BaseAdapter class.

Help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my solution.
Don't know why but my database containing name with forward white space.
so i just add `replaceAll("\\s+","")` and whoa its working like a charm thanks all..

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like below:

```
public int getImageId(Context context, String imageName) {
    return context.getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", getPackageName());
}
```